# Mark start and end of groups

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a `data.table` structure of the form

```
     seller    buyer      month  
1: 50536344 61961225 1993-01-01  
2: 50536344 61961225 1993-02-01 
3: 50536344 61961225 1993-04-01 
4: 50536344 61961225 1993-05-01 
5: 50536344 61961225 1993-06-01
```

where I have `(buyer, seller)` pairs over time. I want to mark the start and end for every pair. For example, we see that there was a pair from January to February, none on March, and one from April to June. Hence, the following would be the expected output:

```
     seller    buyer      month  start    end
1: 50536344 61961225 1993-01-01   True  False
2: 50536344 61961225 1993-02-01  False   True
3: 50536344 61961225 1993-04-01   True  False
4: 50536344 61961225 1993-05-01  False  False
5: 50536344 61961225 1993-06-01  False   True
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `month` is in `Date` class (or similarly for `POSIXt`, `IDateTime` or other classes with `diff` method), you can use the `diff` function do this.

```
# sort data.table
setkeyv(dt, c("seller", "buyer", "month"))
# define start
dt[, start := c(TRUE, diff(month) > 31), by = list(seller, buyer)]
# define end
dt[, end := c(diff(month) > 31, TRUE), by = list(seller, buyer)]
```

EDIT: Per suggestion of @David Arenburg: You can of course define the start and end in one go. This should be slightly faster, although I also find it a bit more difficult to read.

```
dt[, ":=" (start = c(TRUE, diff(month) > 31),
           end = c(diff(month) > 31, TRUE)), 
   by = list(seller, buyer)]
```

EDIT2: Some more explonation of what is happening: The first observation for each pair of seller and buyer will always be the start of a business relationship, so `start = c(TRUE, ...)`. After that a further observation will be the start of a business relationship if and only if the difference in time is larger than a month (31 days), so `diff(month) > 31`. Putting the two things together, you get `c(TRUE, diff(month) > 31)`. 
A similar logic applies for the end, where you have to compare to the next observation instead of the previous one.

Comment: Why do you need to assume `Date` class? just use `IDateTime` from `data.table`, i.e., :`dt[, start:=c(TRUE, diff(as.IDate(month))>31), by=list(seller, buyer)] ; dt[, end:=c(diff(as.IDate(month))>31, TRUE), by=list(seller, buyer)]`

Comment: @David Arenburg: Sure, `IDateTime` works as well, just some sort of date class (with a `diff` method) and not a `character` or `factor`.

Comment: Also, why not do it in one go? `dt[, `:=`(start=c(TRUE, diff(as.IDate(month))>31),
          end=c(diff(as.IDate(month))>31, TRUE)), by = list(seller, buyer)]`. (Add back-quotes around `:=` ). Apart from that (+1) :)

Comment: I'll implement Davids contracted version later on, but I'm still trying to understand what is happening. Could you explain a bit on the logic inside the `c()` expression?