# Find start and end of ranges where data is upper case

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data.frame ystr:

```
    v1
1    a
2    B
3    B
4    C
5    d
6    a
7    B
8    D
```

I want to find the start and end of each group of letters in CAPS so my output would be:

```
    groupId startPos    endPos
1   1       2           4
2   2       7           8
```

I was able to do it with a for loop by looking at each element in order and comparing it to the one before as follows:

```
currentGroupId <-0

for (i in 1:length(ystr[,1])){ 
  if (grepl("[[:upper:]]", ystr[i,])) 
  { 
    if (startCounter == 0) 
    {
       currentGroupId <- currentGroupId +1
       startCounter <-1 
       mygroups[currentGroupId,] <- c(currentGroupId, i, 0)
    }
  }else if (startCounter == 1){
    startCounter <-0
    mygroups[currentGroupId,3]<- i-1
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in R?

This might be similar to [Mark start and end of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954953/mark-start-and-end-of-groups4) but I could not figure out how it would apply in this case.

Comment: `idx <- grep("[[:upper:]]", d$v1) ; 
aggregate(idx ~ cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(idx) != 1)), FUN=range)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by calculating the run-length encoding (`rle`) of the binary indicator for whether your data is upper case, as determined by whether the data is equal to itself when it's converted to upper case.

```
with(rle(d[,1] == toupper(d[,1])),
     data.frame(start=cumsum(lengths)[values]-lengths[values]+1,
                end=cumsum(lengths)[values]))
#   start end
# 1     2   4
# 2     7   8
```

You can see other examples of the use of `rle` by looking at [Stack Overflow answers using this command](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Br%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20rle).

Data:

```
d <- data.frame(v1=c("a", "B", "B", "C", "d", "a", "B", "D"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IRanges` package. It's basically to find the consecutive ranges.

```
d <- data.frame(v1=c("a", "B", "B", "C", "d", "a", "B", "D"))
d.idx <- which(d$v1 %in% LETTERS)
d.idx
# [1] 2 3 4 7 8

library(IRanges)
d.idx.ir <- IRanges(d.idx, d.idx)
reduce(d.idx.ir)
# IRanges of length 2
#     start end width
# [1]     2   4     3
# [2]     7   8     2
```